# How to use CssLink from share point controls in visual studio 2015?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer

I want to add styles to the web part pages in visual studio. Is it possible to use CssLink? How This control works?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CssRegistration` or simple `link` html tag for your custom styles control in `.ascx`:

```
<SharePoint:CssRegistration Name="/_layouts/15/MySolutionFolder/CSS/styles.css?v1" runat="server" />
```

`CssLink` control does big job with SP default styles, read more [here](http://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/2013/05/02/understanding-sharepoint-csslink-and-how-to-add-your-custom-css-in-sharepoint-2010-aspx/).

Comment: Thanks for reply. Whereas I am novice in using Share Point I have put this link in header. It didn't work. Should I change the name? for example this root is ok"C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\1033\STYLES\Themable\COREV15.CSS"

Answer (score 0):

The difference between CssLink and CssRegistration :

http://blogs.catapultsystems.com/tlingenfelder/archive/2007/10/24/the-sharepoint-csslink-and-cssregistration-server-controls/

If you want to add styles to the web part pages , I suggest you can use CssRegistration because CssLink server control must reside on the master page .

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/use-css-to-brand-pages